# Invalid redeclaration of 'rollButtonPressed'

Tags: swift, xcode

I have this error that keeps popping up. I tried cleaning the build folder and it didn't solve this problem. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong? Here's my code.[Image of my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OtK00.png)

Comment: The error message says everything and is easy to fixed out.

Comment: You have created two IBActions of same names. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why you want two same IBActions, but from the image, I can see there are two same IBAction functions, so remove one or rename one of them.

Comment: Oh man. I must be really tired haha. I just noticed that i did do that twice. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I have checked your code and you have created two IBActions , which are of same names. Delete one of them or try renaming one of them.